# How to call an Oracle procedure with parameters of nested table types

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I have created 3 types in my db

```
TYPE ARRAY_MATRICULE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255)
TYPE ARRAY_DOCIN_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255)
TYPE ARRAY_STATUT_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255)
```

And I used these types in a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE (
    matricule IN ARRAY_MATRICULE_TYPE, 
    docIn IN ARRAY_DOCIN_TYPE, 
    statut IN ARRAY_STATUT_TYPE) 
IS
   [...]
BEGIN 
    [...]
END;
```

I'm struck trying to make a call to this procedure with some parameters to do some tests. Can someone provide some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare
 p_1  ARRAY_MATRICULE_TYPE := new ARRAY_MATRICULE_TYPE('abc','yxz');
 p_2  ARRAY_DOCIN_TYPE:= new ARRAY_DOCIN_TYPE('abc','yxz');
 p_3  ARRAY_STATUT_TYPE:= new ARRAY_STATUT_TYPE('abc','yxz');
begin

MYPROCEDURE(   matricule => p_1, 
    docIn  => p_2, 
    statut  => p_3);

end;
```